# SQL statement in PHP, can't use variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am currently trying to create a webpage which can edit details of members of a club. I have a button that Revokes their access to the club. This button is displayed in each row of the HTML table. When the button is pressed, it triggers the function `revoke()` and should update the database to make their status "revoked".

However in my PHP, i can't seem to be able to get it to work in the WHERE clause. It should be `WHERE intID = "whatever their id is"` but it doesn't work. I think this is because i am having trouble passing the ID to the SQL statement.

Here is my code:

```
function revoke(intID1){
    <?php
    $intID=intID1;

    $conn = new mysqli("my server name", "username", "pword", "database");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "UPDATE `members` SET `Status`='Revoked' WHERE `intID`=$intID";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "alert('Record updated successfully')";
    } else {
        echo "alert('Error updating record')". $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
}
```

I am pretty sure the trouble lays in this line:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `members` SET `Status`='Revoked' WHERE `intID`=$intID";
```

I have tried changing the `$intID` to `'$intID'` and messing around with quotation marks but still can't get it to work. I have even tried using `intID1` which is the one originally passed into the function.

I have looked around and found bits about the mysql real escape string but couldn't get that to work either.

Hopefully you guys can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use a JavaScript variable in PHP like that, use AJAX instead.

Comment: if you want to update the row on button click, you need to use ajax to call a backend php script which updates the table

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thank you, I haven’t used AJAX before (I’m an iOS developer) would you be able to answer the question with a method?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ and please use pdo and prepare statments  https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection, if u have only this tiny statment u also can protect the statment with (int)$intID but remmber thaht u never pass user varibles direct to db

Comment: HarryB, @StefanBD has already given enough hints. Please try those. :-)